# URL Encoding CSS parameters

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to development so please don't kill me on this question.

I'm building an ecom site checkout using Cardconnect. In their docs url-encoding CSS parameters are mandatory while in the UAT stage but not in PROD - for validation purposes (https://developer.cardconnect.com/hosted-iframe-tokenizer#iFrame-styling). When I URL encode the CSS for the UAT domain my CSS gets stripped. When toward the non-uat domain, it renders as I expect. I suspect the URL encoding is incorrect but I'm unsure to which part is not right. Any guidence would be appreciated.

```
**CSS Renders**
https://fts.cardconnect.com/itoke/ajax-tokenizer.html?invalidinputevent=true&css=.error{color:red;border-color:red;};input{width:325px;margin-left:10px;padding-left:2px;height:25px;vertical-align:middle;margin-top:25px;font-size:12px;background-color:#ffffff;}
**CSS Doesn't Render**
https://fts-uat.cardconnect.com/itoke/ajax-tokenizer.html?invalidinputevent=true&css%3D.error%7Bcolor%3Ared%3Bborder-color%3Ared%3B%7D%3Binput%7Bwidth%3A325px%3Bmargin-left%3A10px%3Bpadding-left%3A2px%3Bheight%3A25px%3Bvertical-align%3Amiddle%3Bmargin-top%3A25px%3Bfont-size%3A12px%3Bbackground-color%3A%23ffffff%3B%7D
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your encoded URL seems to be invalid.

If you look at the parameters part:

```
?invalidinputevent=true&css%3D.error
```

`css` is a parameter name, it should be followed by an `=` and the encoded value. But you have the `=` also encoded to `%3D` that's why it's invalid.

You should use the `encodeURI` function to encode a full URL:

```
encodeURI('your url')
```

Which returns:

```
https://fts.cardconnect.com/itoke/ajax-tokenizer.html?invalidinputevent=true&css=.error%7Bcolor:red;border-color:red;%7D;input%7Bwidth:325px;margin-left:10px;padding-left:2px;height:25px;vertical-align:middle;margin-top:25px;font-size:12px;background-color:#ffffff;%7D
```

As you can see, this one retained the `css=value` format.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense and easy oversight.